# ReactJS pull config from yml file like with backend java

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring, configuration

My team has a full stack multi-microservice application where the backend java components use spring @value annotation to pull config values from a yml file.

This works quite well and even the java side of our UI component uses it. The yml is stored in:
**MyUI/src/main/resources/application-ui.yml**

That said, is there a way to extend this so that the ReactJS code can also pull config from the same yml file? (E.g. our UI has tables with paging and it wojld be nice to put in config, options for how many records a user can see per page 100,1000,10000)

Our frontend code is stored on the same level as java src i.e.

**MyUI/frontend/src/**

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same requirement for the proj my team's handling and what I have in mind right now is to put a config file in /public folder:

config.js

```
var Config = {
  var1: "value1",
  var2: "value2"
}
```

Then, in /public/index.html file, to add a script call:

index.html

```
<script src="config.js"></script>
```

So that we'd be able to call our config variables like so:

Component.js

```
import React from 'react'
...
const data = window.Config.var1
```

I think it would work well...

Comment: Yeah I had later figured out the same approach too, although I'm wondering what is the best approach. For example for this UI component, I now have two config files (yml for backend and now js for frontend). With java spring the filename isn't hardcoded whereas for this it is.

Comment: How can you not hardcode the config filename, in Spring?

Comment: my understanding of how to implement it isn't very strong but I've have it in my current and last teams. For example in my last team we had dev specific property files like application-name.yml and and environment specific ones like application-tst.yml. not sure if spring just looks inside your java resource folder for any file with application in the name

Comment: In my current team project I use application-local.yml to run locally while we use the component name e.g application-ui.yml in deployed environments

Comment: To call upon the values in the  property files we use spring @value annotation which i quite like

Comment: So it turns out Spring looks for `application-[profile].yml` files, placed in resources. But why would you want different config files in React anyway? Is switching the file in /public dir such a hassle?

Comment: I have different properties for each microservice, and for the UI if i include the properties.js too then I have two property files for the UI (for front and backend). I dont know if this is the best approach as I'm just casually adding another file

Comment: I would (and soon will) be fine with that, since we're not using Spring Cloud, just a few Spring configs and a few React configs. However, I'm also curious for a "cleaner" approach. Too bad noone else is interested..

Comment: So far it looks like there are additional complexities in the CI/CD approach of this (the idea is to make future changes config changes not code changes meaning no build). If will be difficult to pull out the properties file since I think everything is packages together (we use docker/openshift). The alternative I heard is that from back end we expose the config via url and then the front end just reads from the url. The benefit being I can reuse the backend config file (so no mess with devops) although we add complexity by needing to add this functionality now